# Android Unable to launch the Inbox from a notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have the following code that creates a notification when an SMS message is received by the phone.  It displays the notification correctly; however, when the user clicks the notification, nothing happens.  It should open up the SMS inbox so the user can view their message. Thanks in advance.

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
String tickerText = arg0.getString(R.string.newmsg, msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString());
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());
notif.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(), msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString(), contentIntent);
notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500 };
mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.recv_msg_notif_id, notif);
```

Comment: Do not use `content://sms/inbox`. This is not part of the Android SDK. Your application will break on some current devices and may break in future versions of Android.

Comment: Check the Android source code to see how Google does this!

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work.  The following code shows how to accomplish this task:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
notificationIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
```